# Client side image resize and upload does not work on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this nice script from http://www.codeforest.net/html5-image-upload-resize-and-crop to resize an image if too big and upload it:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="doupload2.php">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="fileToUpload">Select Files to Upload</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" />
      <output id="filesInfo"></output>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('filesToUpload').onchange = function(){
        var files = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            resizeAndUpload(files[i]);
        }
    };
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function resizeAndUpload(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {

    var tempImg = new Image();
    tempImg.src = reader.result;
    tempImg.onload = function() {

        var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
        var tempW = tempImg.width;
        var tempH = tempImg.height;
        if (tempW > tempH) {
            if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
               tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
               tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else {
            if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
               tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
               tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = tempW;
        canvas.height = tempH;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
            document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = 'Done!';
        };

        xhr.open('POST', 'doupload2.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var data = 'image=' + dataURL;
        xhr.send(data);
      }

   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

It works fine on desktop, but can someone tell me how to make it work on  smartphones?

Comment: Well there is no problem with just uploading but then I have to increase the upload size limit to make all the 10/10/30 mb images to pass. I will take the best good enough solution to resize them client side before upload

Comment: have you tried github's https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload or https://github.com/mgkimsal/jsclientshrinker

Comment: I will take a look at that later, thanks